# PHP(Zend) & Smarty - problems generating .doc file and http headers

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers, content-type, httpresponse

i'm using the Zend Framework and Smarty Template generator on a project, i'm new to this work and also to ZF and Smarty. Anyway, on an action there's a clickable link for a .doc report generation. Once clicked, it generates a .doc file using [HtmlToDoc](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2763-PHP-Convert-HTML-into-Microsoft-Word-documents.html) class by this method:

```
$htmltodoc_instance -> createDoc($body ,
                  'filename.doc',
                   TRUE);  
/* the last parameter TRUE means: download or save the file. it set the HTTP headers 
'Content-type: application/octet-stream' and 'Content-Disposition: attachment; 
 filename="..."', forcing the browser to open a download dialog for filename.doc
```

before that, it has been renderd the current action by

```
 $this -> view -> obj_to_render = $obj_to_render.
```

with obj_to_render placed in the view, while $obj_to_render is generally the formatted html code by Smarty template engine. 
I don't know if it is the cause, but it seems that this cause the problem: the header of .doc download dialog is somehow 'overriden' by the next header of view's rendering, and so the .doc file's output is not succesful. i've tried to put an exit() after createDoc() method call, but it doens help much. output is diferent, but it still doesn't display the informations i need. Anybody know how to divide this two operations and then obtain the right file output?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function h2dAction()
{
    $content = '<strong>wow! it\'s alive!</strong>';

    $htmltodoc = new HTML_TO_DOC();
    $htmltodoc->docFile = 'wow.doc';
    @$htmltodoc->createDoc($content, $htmltodoc->docFile, true);
    die;
}
```

GDocs works fine with this file. cant test on MS Word, i dont have it :)